# A verb for undoing a withdrawal?

Tags: single-word-requests

When someone withdrew something, and then later decided to undo that action, how would such a reversal be called? I can think of "re-introducing", or "putting back", but maybe there's a better choice of words?

Comment: Your choices are perfect in some contexts. "She withdrew her hand from the hob, then replaced it when she realized it wasn't switched on." "They withdrew the remark, then repeated it." "He withdrew his finger, then re-inserted it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term **[redeposit](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/redeposit)** is commonly used in financial and similar contexts.

> United now charges most of its members $150 to redeposit canceled miles.

In a non-financial context, such as removing a photo from a desk, I'd use **replace**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not talking about finance "reinsertion" might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As others have it depends on the context;
i.e., what word describes the initial process. 
For example, if a student withdraws from a class/course,
or from a school/college/university altogether,
she might [***reenroll***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reenroll) (or ***re-enroll***).

Note: MW and Wiktionary seem to be the only sites
that have explicit entries for this.